# How to change store theme dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, dynamic

I am new to Magento. But i got a requirement. Below is the requirement:

1. On the Frontend, user is having an option to select the theme from a given list of themes (Drop Down).
2. Upon selecting a theme, the selected theme should be applied to the store dynamically.

Please help me with an example, how to implement this feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649587/set-package-and-theme-at-run-time-in-magento go through this. You need to integrate select with this code.

Answer (score 2):

you can set theme like that on front-end..

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('modern');
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.
1. I created a new module to change the theme dynamically.
2. After changing the theme as per above code, i redirected it to the home page.
3. But after redirecting to home page, theme is not updating.

Comment: On Front end where should i place the code.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/change-theme-dynamically-from-frontend-doesnt-update-xml-layout?noredirect=1#comment26170_17525  follow this answer

Comment: in your header.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

In order to fulfill,your require,

- ***Need to create a custom controller***
- ***On dropdown changes,it will hit this controller's an action.***
- ***On this action,the selected theme  will be selected and back you last
  page***

If you want apply a theme  to custom frontend ui then try this:

> Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
>                   ->setPackageName($package)
>                   ->setTheme($theme);

**This concept is like  currency change.**

***controller code seems to like :***

> ```
> <?php
> class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
> public function indexAction(){
>   $package=$this->getRequest()->getParam('package');
>   $theme=$this->getRequest()->getParam('theme');
>
>                 Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
>                     ->setPackageName($package)
>                     ->setTheme($theme);
>       // this code is redirec to you last page/same page
>        $this->_redirectUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());          
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but once the page is redirecting the theme is changing to 'rwd' from 'default'