# Apply new exception theme for I-Pad portrait mode

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, design

I have a requirement where my client gives me different design for I-Pad portrait mode And tell me that no need to change design for landscape mode.

So I need to know what is the user agent matched expression for I-Pad portrait mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that,**Magento does not have feature to Track current view is portrait or landscape.**

So it not possible from design exception setting.

- Only possible , *detect iPhone View mode landscape or portrait* using
  [orientationchanged event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850472/how-do-i-detect-when-the-iphone-goes-into-landscape-mode-via-javascript-is-ther).
- and then using Ajax Change set a **Session variable** which carry
  current view is portrait at current session.

Then using event  `controller_action_layout_load_before` change theme

Follow below to How change theme using event

[Is there any way to set different theme depends on customer group?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8079/is-there-any-way-to-set-different-theme-depends-on-customer-group)

Comment: Though your answer not help me completely but it  help me to find a way